# awk: Print between regexps which are in different columns

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

I am trying print the contents of a column in a file between two regular expressions which are in different columns though. A sample file looks like this

```
Run Summary Paddle Status = 613  (hex 265) Cd+Bi paddle
   Run     To      Time    Current    C mon       Ufis      Charge
                   (sec)    (uA)                             (uC)
  23626   35950   1797.5     99.0   5.641e+05   2.289e+06   1.779e+05
  23630   34587   1729.3    104.9   5.439e+05   2.234e+06   1.815e+05
  23634   34982   1749.1     92.8   5.526e+05   2.100e+06   1.623e+05
  23638   35950   1797.5     95.0   5.698e+05   2.204e+06   1.707e+05
  23642   36135   1806.8     99.6   5.710e+05   2.317e+06   1.800e+05
  23646   36130   1806.5    100.0   5.747e+05   2.322e+06   1.807e+05
  23650   36121   1806.0    100.2   5.733e+05   2.324e+06   1.810e+05
  23654   36123   1806.2    100.2   5.752e+05   2.323e+06   1.809e+05
   Sum  2418821 120941.1            3.772e+07   1.513e+08   1.193e+07

Run Summary Paddle Status = 357  (hex 165) Cd paddle
   Run     To      Time    Current    C mon       Ufis      Charge
                   (sec)    (uA)                             (uC)
  23625   36001   1800.0    100.8   3.342e+05   2.329e+06   1.814e+05
  23629   36132   1806.6    100.8   3.307e+05   2.343e+06   1.821e+05
  23633   35882   1794.1     97.6   3.565e+05   2.257e+06   1.751e+05
  23637   36139   1807.0     99.3   3.545e+05   2.307e+06   1.795e+05
  23641   36133   1806.7     99.3   3.598e+05   2.307e+06   1.794e+05
  23645   36144   1807.2     99.7   3.635e+05   2.315e+06   1.802e+05
  23649   36132   1806.6    100.1   3.648e+05   2.321e+06   1.808e+05
  23653   36123   1806.2    100.1   3.695e+05   2.318e+06   1.808e+05
  23657   36152   1807.6     99.9   3.684e+05   2.318e+06   1.805e+05
   Sum  2404062 120203.1            2.186e+07   1.505e+08   1.193e+07
```

What I need to do is print the 1st column that occurs between two rows after the regular expression `Cd+Bi` and the first occurrence of `Sum` not included. Then the same will be repeated for the regexp `Cd`.  My output will be then two files (although this is not strict) that will have the following contents

file with `Cd+Bi`

```
23626   
23630 
23634  
23638  
23642   
23646  
23650
```

file with `Cd`

```
23625
23629
23633
23637
23641
23645
23649
23653
23657
```

I tried using the following oneliners, but I can't reproduce what I want.

1. This doesn't print anything `awk '$9 ~ /Cd+Bi/, $1 ~ /Sum/' file`
2. This prints all lines that contain Sum `awk '$9 ~ /Cd+Bi/{flag=1;next}$1 ~ /Sum/' file`

Any idea on how to produce the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '$9=="Cd+Bi",$1=="Sum"{ if ($1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/) print $1 }' file
23626
23630
23634
23638
23642
23646
23650
23654
```

Note that the last line contains `23654` which was not included in your example.

And for `Cd`:

```
$ awk '$9=="Cd",$1=="Sum"{ if ($1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/) print $1 }' file
23625
23629
23633
23637
23641
23645
23649
23653
23657
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `awk` solution:

With `Cd+Bi`:

```
awk -v s='Cd+Bi' '$9==s{p=1} $1=="Sum"{p=0} p && $1+0 == $1{print $1}' file
```

```
23626
23630
23634
23638
23642
23646
23650
23654
```

and with `Cd`:

```
awk -v s='Cd' '$9==s{p=1} $1=="Sum"{p=0} p && $1+0 == $1{print $1}' file
```

```
23625
23629
23633
23637
23641
23645
23649
23653
23657
```